# Lisp list number of element

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm preparing myself for my upcoming exam in LISP and I've come across a problem I can't solve, so I was hoping someone more experienced might help me out.Im trying to make a recursive lisp program that returns the position of an element n from a list but i cant use nth.I need to verify if n is in the list between 0 and length of the list -1 if the element is not in the list a error message should appear.
Something like this:`(my-list '(1 2 3) 4) =>"error the list has only 3 elements"`
Can someone help me with this problem Im still a novice when it comes to LISP

My code so far:

```
(defun no-nth (n list)
  (declare (type (integer 0) n) (type list))
  (if (or (zerop n) (null list))
    (cons (car list) (no-nth (1- n) (cdr list)))))
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: (defun no-nth (n list)(declare(type (integer 0) n)(type list))(if (or (zerop n) (null list))(cons (car list) (no-nth (1- n) (cdr list)))))this is what iv made so far but it dosent work :(

Answer (score 1):

Use labels to make a helper. You have the list and an index as argument. When the list is empty you return whatever you do when it's not found, perhaps nil. If not you check the first element with your search term and return index if it's a match. If not you recur with rest of the list and the increment of the index.

Answer (score 0):

Both your problem description and code are confused.

Let's settle for the name `no-nth` and the parameter order `n`, then `list`.

So you have 3 different cases:

1. n < 0 or list is empty => element could not be found => return `nil`
2. n = 0 => result is first element of the list (assuming that the first position is index 0)
3. n > 0 => recurse by decrementing n and shortening the list by 1.

The code would then be:

```
(defun no-nth (n list)
  (cond
   ((or (< n 0) (null list)) nil)  ; (1) index not in list
   ((zerop n) (car list))          ; (2) index = 0 => return first element of list
   (t (no-nth (1- n) (cdr list))))); (3) index > 0 => recurse down
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you think of something like this?

```
(defun no-nth (n list)
  (labels ((nth-intern (n list)
             (if (zerop n) (car list)
               (nth-intern (1- n) (cdr list)))))
    (if (< (list-length list) n)
        (error "LIST has no Nth element.")
      (nth-intern n list))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun help-func (n list)
(cond
    ((= n 1) (car list))
    (T (help-func (1- n) (cdr list)))))

(defun no-nth (n list)
(cond
    ((or (< n 0) (>= n (length list))) 'invalid-index)
    (T (help-func n list))))

(print (no-nth 2 '(1 2 3)))
(print (no-nth 21 '(1 2 3)))
```

If you want to see the result: http://ideone.com/zW0gvD

First you check if the index is valid, if it's not, you return invalid-index.

 If it's valid, you call help-func, a recursive function.

Recursively, you decrease n until you get to n=1 (or n=0, if you want a zero base index element).